# .remove() ignore .delay()?

Tags: jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sny7P/) there is an example :

```
<div id='example'>
    ciao
</div>

$('#example').fadeOut(600).delay(600).remove();
```

I want to fadeout the element, than remove it, but looks like that `.remove()` ignore `.delay()` (so the element is removed immediatly).

How can I fix this trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.remove` is not about animating, so `.delay` has no effect.

What you can do is passing a function which gets executed when the animation has finished (the callback argument - see http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

```
$('#example').fadeOut(600, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Sny7P/1/

Answer (score 4):

Specify a callback instead

```
$('#example').fadeOut(600, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using delay, pass a callback to fadeOut:

```
$('#example').fadeOut(600, function() {
    $("#example").remove();
});
```